# Fitting a distribution to random variable in R when the data is available for minimum of those random variables

Tags: r, distributions, extreme-value

I am new in R. I have the following problem:

I have a dataset which presents the minimum of a set of n random variables (x1, x2,..., xn). 
The formula is Min(x1, x2,...,xn) = 1-(1-F(x))^n. 
It can be assumed that the random variables xi's are IID.

Now I want to fit a distribution on xi's. In other words I would like to know what type of distribution does each of the random variable follow.

How can I do it with R?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. (Assume random variables are IID and normally distributed)

Comment: To *fit* a distribution, you need to stipulate what the possible $F$ might be.  What, then, are you assuming about $F$?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: You are confusing the minimum random variable with its cdf.